# How to change the size of an angular component?

Tags: angular, components

I explain: I use a file upload component in several other parent components of my application.
In some cases I would like to vary the size of this component
For example, when I inject the component into a parent `AComponent`, I would like my component to have a size:

```
height: 50px;
width:100px;
```

If I insert the same component in a parent `BComponent`, I want the size to be:

```
height: 200px;
width:400px;
```

thanks for help

Comment: You should design your component to be responsive and control the actual size from the AComponent and BComponent respectively. The file upload component should not concern itself with how big it needs to be.